# Unable to install hadoop on macosx

Tags: macos, hadoop

I am unable to run hadoop on my Max OSX.

When I run `hadoop version` -> nothing happens

When I run `sudo hadoop version` -> it shows my hadoop version. I read somewhere that I shldn't be using `sudo` to run hadoop. but anyway this tells me that my hadoop is installed?

Because `hadoop version` returns nothing, I am unable to open any nodes. Everytime I try to start a node with `start-dfs.sh`, nothing happens as well. Does anyone knows what's happening here? I've look through all the configuration files multiple times to ensure that I have set them right. Not sure where the problem lies here.

---

What i did:

1. Followed the instructions from [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)
   In my config files I edited:

**etc/hadoop/core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In fact I managed to run everything before.

I am not sure what I did after tht, but I am unable to start the nodes again. I think it might be because I failed to close my nodes before I shut down my computer before?

Comment: It would help if you added your config files and mentioned how you installed/downloaded Hadoop

Comment: try downloading cloudera it might help